# Remove GMSMarker when tapped

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, uialertcontroller

How do you enable a GMSMarker to be removed when tapped? I would like when a marker is tapped an alert controller to show up and ask for whether the user wants to save or remove the tapped marker. So how would I get the tapped marker to be removed when the 'remove' button is pressed? and also how do I get it to save for when the user accesses the map later if the 'save' is pressed. I have this basic structure so far but not sure how to implement the functionality:

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

    print("didtapmarker")
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add this place to wishlist?",
                                  message: "Would you like to add this to your list?",
                                  preferredStyle: .alert)

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",
                                   style: .default)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Remove",
                                     style: .default)


    //alert.addAction(defaultAction)
    alert.addAction(saveAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)


    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
     return false
}
```

So where would I go from here? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a marker from a map, set `map` to `nil`:

```
marker.map = nil
```

You can put the above code in `handler` closure when you initialize the `UIAlertAction`:

```
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Remove",
                                 style: .default) {
    _ in marker.map = nil
}
```

To save the marker is a little bit more complicated. If you want to save only one marker at a time, you can use `UserDefaults`.

```
if let latitude = marker.latitude?.doubleValue, let longitude = marker.longitude?.doubleValue {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(latitude, forKey: "lat")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(longitude, forKey: "lon")
}
```

To show the saved marker on the map on `viewDidLoad`, first retrieve the saved longitude and latitude:

```
let latitude = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "lat")
let longitude = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "lon")
```

And use the values to construct a new `GMSMarker`.

If you want to save multiple markers on the map, you need to use Core Data. This is a little bit more tricky than `UserDefaults`. I suggest you to read some tutorials first. Then, you can read the code of a similar project that I did - [LongLatMap](https://github.com/Sweeper777/LongLatMap).

Comment: Perfect. Looks like I will need to delve into Core Data and how to use it as I want the user to be able to save multiple markers. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the map to nil and the marker will be gone.

```
marker.map = nil
```